# How to draw labels last to make sure they are not obscured?

Tags: graphviz

it looks like both nodes and edges are drawn *after* (x)labels, and are therefore sometimes obscuring them. -- is it possible to have labels be drawn after everything else, so that they are always on top?

[image]

---

edit:

`outputorder="edgesfirst"` helps with the edges at least, but but node xlabels are still sometimes obscured by other nodes.

---

edit 2:

my workaround for now: use `svg` as output format. move all `<text>` tags to the end of the file. convert to pdf.

Comment: Please show what you have and gives the problems, so others can "correct" / "complete" and see where the problem is.

Comment: added a picture @albert

Comment: Would be useful to show the ode as well with which this is obtained (finding problem and no typing required to get the same result)

Answer (score 0):

Try `outputorder="nodesfirst"` (i.e. labels last)